# How to echo class path variable to a file

Tags: java, ant, jar

I'm trying to get all the contents on my main classpath to get written to a file by my Ant buildscript:

```
<path id="main.class.path">
    <fileset dir="${lib.main.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

When I hover over `main.class.path`, Ant/Eclipse launches a tooltip that shows the items on that classpath:

> C:\Users\myUser\workbench\eclipse\workspace\myProj\lib\main\ant-junit-1.6.5.jar

etc. (The actual list has about 30 JARs on it.)

**I want this list written to a file called deps.txt under my `dist/` directory.**

I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to make `main.class.path` an Ant variable, or how to at least access it in the `<echo>` task:

```
<echo file="${dist.dir}/deps.txt" message="${???}"/>
```

Am I way-off base here, or even remotely close?!?

And for those of you out there that, instead of answering this question, would just comment *Why would you want to do this?*, my answer is simple: I just want a small text file in my JAR that serves as a visual reminder (for my future me) for what its dependencies are.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <pathconvert property="expanded.main.class.path" refid="main.class.path"/>

  <target name="everything">
    <echo message="${expanded.main.class.path}"
          file="${dist.dir}/deps.txt"/>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 14):

Straightforward via :

```
<echo file="${dist.dir}/deps.txt">${ant.refid:main.class.path}</echo>
<!-- or -->
<echo file="${dist.dir}/deps.txt">${toString:main.class.path}</echo>
```

${ant.refid:main.class.path} or ${toString:main.class.path} is a csv property which holds all items from your path with its nested fileset(s) ([resourcecollections](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) in general) separated with ';'
see Ant Manual [Properties and PropertyHelpers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html)
If you want another separator you need to use [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) which has a `pathsep attribute`, i.e. for a new line after each file in your deps.txt use `pathsep="${line.separator}"`